# Django: Static vs Assets

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django,

I'm adding new CSS files to my application!

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

EDIT:
I'm using `{% load static %}` before rendering the teamplate!

I can't see any change when add files to the /static/ folder
(it works when adding them to /assets/)

My Question:
What the deference between the two folders?  Do I need to add the new files to /static/ anyway? Because I see the var `{% static .. %}`

Comment: did you use the `{% load staticfiles %}` tag before it?

Comment: see this tutorial `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial06/`

Comment: I'm using `{% load static %}` before rendering the HTML codes!

Comment: not exactly, it should be `{% load staticfiles %}` anyway.

Comment: Thank you @fish_ball should I add the new css files to both (static and assets) folders?

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser cache?